# SPA Authenticating with AAD using msal.js experiencing infinite redirect loop

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I am writing an SPA using Vue.js, authenticating the user from Azure Active Directory (AAD) using OAuth and OpenID. I have searched for a long time for the best way to do this, and have **consistently been referred to a library called [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)**. This is working, in a way, as I am able to get the token id successfully. But, immediately after getting the token id, the page always automatically redirects back to the authorization URL. This **infinite loop has been reported as a bug [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/498)**. I have tried the workarounds recommended on that bug report page, but they are not working for me.

So, my question is, does anyone have any advice as to what I can try next? One person in that bug report thread said they are writing their own plugin instead of using msal.js, but that seems like a big undertaking. I have a hard time imagining there is not a better solution out there.

Comment: Could you add the code where you configure MSAL and acquire tokens?